# JSF Primefaces:redirect to specific page on p:tab click

Tags: jsf, onclick, primefaces, href, tabbed

I would like to utilize `p:tabView` for horizontal site menu.

When tab is clicked,that user should be redirected in non-ajax style to the specific page.

Is it possible to inject to each tab (e.g. inside `p:tab` tag) `href` link ?

Or there is already some alternative to it?

Comment: So, `<p:menubar>` is not an option? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf

Comment: Looks like suitable,I will give feedback as soon try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `p:tabView` in a template and set the `activeIndex` property according to the view ID of the current page. It's an ugly hack, but certainly do-able. I did something similar, using a `p:menu` on the left for navigation in the control panel section of my site.

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces 3.4 now has a [`p:tabMenu` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabMenu.jsf) that may be of use.
You will have to manage the active tab manually since this is an [undeveloped feature](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2090).